# Capturing group of numbers to place somewhere else in parenthesis with regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex

Okay, so I have a huge XML like this:

```
<imgdir name="5010000">
<string name="name" value="Sunny Day"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a brightly smiling sun floating over you. On the KeyConfig, configure this on a button of your choice to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
<imgdir name="5010001">
<string name="name" value="Moon &amp; the Stars"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a brightly smiling moon floating around in a sea of stars over you. On the KeyConfig, configure this on a button of your choice to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
<imgdir name="5010002">
<string name="name" value="Colorful Rainbow"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a rainbow in its full 7 colors floating next to you. Designate a HotKey to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
<imgdir name="5010003">
<string name="name" value="Little Devil"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see Lilly the cute little devil floating around next to you. Designate a HotKey to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
```

and I want to take every value of "imgdir name" and add it to the end of "string name="name"" in parenthesis, like so:

```
<imgdir name="5010000">
<string name="name" value="Sunny Day (5010000)"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a brightly smiling sun floating over you. On the KeyConfig, configure this on a button of your choice to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
<imgdir name="5010001">
<string name="name" value="Moon &amp; the Stars (5010001)"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a brightly smiling moon floating around in a sea of stars over you. On the KeyConfig, configure this on a button of your choice to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
<imgdir name="5010002">
<string name="name" value="Colorful Rainbow (5010002)"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see a rainbow in its full 7 colors floating next to you. Designate a HotKey to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
<imgdir name="5010003">
<string name="name" value="Little Devil (5010003)"/>
<string name="desc" value="A special effect in which you&apos;ll see Lilly the cute little devil floating around next to you. Designate a HotKey to turn the effect on/off."/>
</imgdir>
```

I've tried looking into "capture groups" and I think that's what I need but I can't really figure out how to get them to output where I want them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the find:

```
<imgdir name="(\d+)">(\s+)<string name="name" value="(.*?)"
```

And this as the replace:

```
<imgdir name="$1">$2<string name="name" value="$3 \($1\)"
```

This captures the digits in the `imgdir` name attribute and the value of the `string` value attribute.  The captured groups (`$1`, `$2` and `$3`) are then used in the replace to put the required values back in.  `$2` matches whitespace, or the newlines, to ensure they stay in the same format (`\r\n`, or `\n`) as they started.

Comment: There were a few errors, possibly due to inconsistencies in the .xml, but I was able to fix them by hand. Otherwise, worked perfectly, thanks a ton!